# From Multiple Select - When Button is clicked it should concatenate the strings and Go to the URL

Tags: html, forms, url, select, concatenation

When user selects the option from following Select and clicks the button ... the values should be concatenate and should go to specific url !

for example, if user selects the product2 & product6 & product8, then on clicking the button, the values should be concatenated and create & go to that url, like **example.com/268**

```
<select id="one">
    <option value="default">Select Product</option>
    <option class="s" value="1">product1</option>
    <option class="q" value="2">product2</option>
    <option class="q" value="3">product3</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
    <option value="default">Select Version</option>
    <option class="l" value="4">product4</option>
    <option class="l" value="5">product5</option>
    <option class="c" value="6">product6</option>
</select>

<select id="three">
    <option value="default">Select OS</option>
    <option class="o" value="7">product7</option>
    <option class="o" value="8">product8</option>
    <option class="o" value="9">product9</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I see no button in your code, nor do I see the technology you wish to use (plain javascript, jQuery, mootools ...). But most importantly: I don't see *any* effort on your behalf in solving this problem. What have you tried? Can you show us any (non-working) code?

Comment: I agree with @Kippie about the lack of accompanying code. Also I assumed you're using JavaScript but I just noticed it's not among your tags.

Comment: @Kippie -yes i did not included my efforts ... its my mistake... but i thought that the code i presented are well enough to understand that this case of Html Form ... and i am not a java programmer so its very very difficult for me to even try to write a java code... but thanks you both for giving time to it !

Comment: @Tumtum Many Thanks for providing the solution...am rushing to try the codes you provided. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using your code :)

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="one">
        <option value="default">Select Product</option>
        <option class="s" value="1">product1</option>
        <option class="q" value="2">product2</option>
        <option class="q" value="3">product3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="two">
        <option value="default">Select Version</option>
        <option class="l" value="4">product4</option>
        <option class="l" value="5">product5</option>
        <option class="c" value="6">product6</option>
    </select>

    <select id="three">
        <option value="default">Select OS</option>
        <option class="o" value="7">product7</option>
        <option class="o" value="8">product8</option>
        <option class="o" value="9">product9</option>
    </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val1 = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var val3 = document.getElementById("three").value;
    if(val1 != "default" && val2 != "default" && val3 != "default")
        window.location.href = "http:www.example.com/" + val1 + val2 + val3;
    else
        alert("Fill out everything please!");
}, false);
```

And a JSFiddle to see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/KfH9m/1

Comment: Simply superb @Tumtum, the above example and code you provided has exactly solved my problem ... Many Thanks !